# tikz or tikzmath messing up units?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, lengths

I would like to work on variable using different kinds of latex unit of length.
I'm declaring variables including the units, but it's making a big mess. If a unit is given in a calculation, the length is properly converted, but if no unit is given, the value is returned converted to pt, but with units not always remembered.

my MWE to show that what is obtained is not what expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{\VA=15mm;};

\draw (0,0) -- (\VA,0) node [right] {\VA (expected: 15mm)};
\draw (0,-1) -- (\VA mm,-1) node [right] {\VA (expected: 15mm)};
\draw (0,-2) -- (\VA +10 mm,-2) node [right]  {$\VA + 10$ mm};
\draw (0,-3) -- (\VA +1 cm,-3) node [right]  {$\VA + 1$ cm};
\draw (0,-4) -- (\VA pt,-4) node [right] {$\VA$ pt=15mm};
\draw (0,-5) -- (\VA/10,-5) node [right] {\VA/10 (expected: 1.5mm line)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first line is expected to be 15 mm long results in a 42 cm line exceeding the page width if my interpretation is correct.

Is there any way to get a more predictable results and work properly using length?

[image: compilation result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask `\show\VA`, you will see that TeX answers

```
> \VA=macro:
->42.67912.
```

If you use a “naked” number in a coordinate, this is taken as a multiple of the unit length, by default 1cm. So the first line is more than 42cm long, which accounts for the 1009pt overfull box.

If you use `\VA mm`, then you get 42.67912mm. And so on.

If you want that `\VA` stands for 15mm, use `\def\VA{15mm}` (inside a `tikzpicture`, of course).

Comment: OK, this is what I guessed from my tries from the lines 1, 2 and 5, but doesn't explain lines 3 and 4 where I got the "expected" lengths. If \VA is a 'naked' 42.67912, how can 42.67912 + 10 mm (or 1 cm) make a 25 mm line?

Comment: @HérissonDidier I'm not sure what are the precise parsing rules when units are used with “pure numbers”. I guess that the presence of a unit makes Ti*k*Z into using points.

Comment: ok. If \VA+10mm is understood as 42.67912pt+10mm, which is right and what i want, the weird thing is that if there is no unit, \VA is just considered as a naked number even,  using \def is much more reliable, it just works as it should, and produces errors if one tries to input '\VA mm', as it should... That's weird, as I found \tikzmath{} an easy way to define variables inside the tikzpicture...